# Disconnecting charger while Macbook Pro Retina is still turned on

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

Is it safe to disconnect (unplug the charger from) my Macbook Pro Retina 13" while the computer is turned on and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely it is safe.

It has been designed for that, it does not have a locked in plug, but a magnetically coupled plug for that reason.

I have done that on purpose or by accident (tripping over the cable) many times without problems.

Comment: Yes. Buscar is correct.

Comment: So, to clarify, this means that I can connect and disconnect the charger to and from my MBPr while I'm still using the computer itself?

Comment: correct you can do that at any time.